# How to obtain Google Fit data from Smart watch Wearable device Fossil Q Founder? Which complies BLE requirements? In Android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-sensors, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I am trying to pull the data from Intel's Fossil Android based Smartwatch (BLE device) via Google Fit Android SDK. The BLE Scan seem to happen, pairing occurs but inside the result Callback it doesn't go to onDeviceFound (I can proceed from there if it reaches). It eventually times out within few seconds from the start of the scan.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your code and error logs that you encounter? You may want to check the document regarding [Use Bluetooth Sensors](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/ble-sensors), to review proper implementation and for best practices when managing user data, see [Responsible use of Google Fit](https://developers.google.com/fit/overview#responsible_use_of_google_fit). Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the docs link. I did go through all of that thoroughly but it didn't help. This is my Class file and I can call startBleScan from my MainActivity, the BleScan seems to be working, but after that it doesn't proceed to go on to onDeviceFound method.

public class BlueToothDevicesManager {

```
private static final String TAG = "BlueToothDevicesManager";
private static final int REQUEST_BLUETOOTH = 1001;
private Main2Activity mMonitor;
private GoogleApiClient mClient;

public BlueToothDevicesManager(Main2Activity monitor, GoogleApiClient client) {
    mMonitor = monitor;
    mClient = client;

}

public void startBleScan() {
    if (mClient.isConnected()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Google account is connected");
    }
    BleScanCallback callback = new BleScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onDeviceFound(BleDevice device) {
            Log.i(TAG, "BLE Device Found: " + device.getName());
            claimDevice(device);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScanStopped() {

            Log.i(TAG, "BLE scan stopped");
        }
    };


    PendingResult result = Fitness.BleApi.startBleScan(mClient, new StartBleScanRequest.Builder()
            .setDataTypes(DataType.TYPE_POWER_SAMPLE, DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CADENCE, DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, DataType.TYPE_SPEED, DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SAMPLE, DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA, DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT, DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE)
            .setBleScanCallback(callback)
            .build());

    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull Result result) {
            Status status = result.getStatus();
            if (!status.isSuccess()) {
                String a = status.getStatusCode() + "";
                Log.i(TAG, a);
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {

                    case FitnessStatusCodes.DISABLED_BLUETOOTH:
                        try {

                            status.startResolutionForResult(mMonitor, REQUEST_BLUETOOTH);

                        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "SendIntentException: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                        break;
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "BLE scan unsuccessful");
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "ble scan status message: " + status.getStatusMessage());
                Log.i(TAG, "Ble scan successful: " + status.getResolution());


            }
        }
    });
}

public void claimDevice(BleDevice device) {
    //Stop ble scan

    //Claim device
    PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = Fitness.BleApi.claimBleDevice(mClient, device);
    pendingResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {

        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull Status st) {
            if (st.isSuccess()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Claimed device successfully");
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Did not successfully claim device");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}